# Prove outer measure of $\varnothing$ is $0$.

Tags: measure-theory, proof-verification

Attempt:

$\mu^*(E) = \inf\{\sum\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}l(I_n): (I_n:n\in\mathbb{N}) \text{ such that } \bigcup
\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}I_n \supset E \}$

$l\big((a,b)\big) = b-a \text{ if } b \text{ and } a \text{ are finite.}$

Since $\varnothing= (a,a) \hspace{2mm}\forall a\in\mathbb{R}, l(\emptyset)=0$.

Consider the sequence of sets $F$ where $F_n = 
\varnothing\hspace{1mm} \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Since $\bigcup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\varnothing\supset \varnothing$, $l(\bigcup\limits_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\varnothing)=l(\varnothing)=0 \geq \mu^*(\varnothing)\geq 0$.

So $\mu^*(\varnothing) = 0$.

---

This seems too good to be true. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If $A\subset B$ then $\mu^*(A)\le \mu^*(B)$ and now $\emptyset \subset \{1\}$ so $0\le \mu^*(\emptyset)\le\mu^*(\{1\})=0 $ since measure of singleton is zero so $\mu^*(\emptyset)=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the definition of $\mu^{*}$, the empty set is not considered as an open interval so you cannot use $(a,a)$. Instead, use the fact that $\varnothing \subseteq (0,\frac 1n)$ so $\mu^{*} (\varnothing) \leq \frac 1 n$ for all $n$.

Comment: I'm guessing I have to take the limit of both sides?

Comment: Yes,you have to let $n \to \infty$ to get $\mu (\emptyset)=0$.

Comment: @mathebeginner If $0 \leq x \leq \frac{1}{n}$ holds for every natural number $n$, then $x=0$. No limits needed (although you can use them if you want to)

Answer (score 1):

Contrapositive is more fun: assume that the measure of the empty set is not infinity $\mu(\varnothing)\neq 0$.

Then the set $\varnothing\subset\left(a,\frac{\mu(\varnothing)}{2}+a\right)$, but the latter has a measure that is smaller than the first, which is impossibile.